# Can I sort a SELECT statement on the amount of child objects on another table in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table called Parent and another table called Child. The Child table has a parent_id and a description on it. I would like to do a query where we get Parent objects and order them by description. HOWEVER, if there are more than 2 Child Objects, I want them to come after the other objects. Is this possible with a case statement?

If it's any help, I am using mysqli with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to collect the count, then select from that:

```
select columns
from (
    select p.columns, count(c.parent_id) as childcount
    from parent p
    join child c on c.parent_id = p.id
    group by p.columns
) subquery
order by childcount > 2, description
```

The trick here is `childcount > 2` which in MySQL is `0` if false and `1` if true, so more than 2 children parents will appear after all parents with 2 or less, and within each bracket of results, parents are sorted by description.

Note that `columns` means the list of columns in `parent` you want returned from your query.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, we do not need case statement for this.

```
select * 
from parent p
order by
(select count(*) 
from child c
where p.parent_id = c.parent_id)
```

if you want to seperate 2 and less from more than 2 it can be like this

```
select * 
from parent p
where 
(select count(*) 
from child c 
where c.parent_id = p.parent_id) <= 2
order by p.description
union
select * 
from parent p
where 
(select count(*) 
from child c 
where c.parent_id = p.parent_id) > 2
order by p.description
```